# How to Prove that if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k}$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Prove that if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k}$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

I already know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k}$ converges pointwise on $[0, 1]$ 
by either Abel's or Dirichlet's Test for pointwise convergence.
Now, can I do this proof without Dirichlet's Test for uniform convergence? 
I don't want to use it because, in the text, 
this question came before Dirichlet's Test for uniform convergence.

Since we don't know that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely, 
we can't say that for all $x \in [0, 1]$, $|{a_k}{x^k}| \le |a_k|$ and apply the Weiertrass M-test.

Also, since we don't know if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k$ is an alternating series, 
we can't say that that since $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k}$ converges pointwise, 
let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k}{x^k} = A(x)$ and observe that for all $x \in [0, 1]$,
$$|A(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_k}{x^k}| \le |a_{n+1}|x^{n+1} \le |a_{n+1}| \rightarrow 0$$
as $n$ goes to infinity.

A clue is sufficient.  I really want to think this problem through.  TY!

Comment: @Arthur A series without a variable can't converge uniformly. It needs to be a series of functions for the notion to make sense. Also, the $|a_k|$ are bounded, but that only gives pointwise convergence unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @ZachL. I'm confusing it with absolute convergence, sorry.

Comment: Another attempt, then. Set $A_k = \sum_{i = 0}^k a_i$ and $f_k(x) =  \sum_{i = 0}^k a_ix^i$ for notational convinience. Given an $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ so that $|A_\infty - A_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n> N$. Such an $N$ exists by convergence of $A_\infty$. Now if we can prove that $|f_\infty(x) - f_k(x)| \leq |A_\infty - A_k|$ for all $x$ and $k$, we're done. If you write out the sum on each side, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: You could use [Abel's lemma](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Abel%27s_Lemma), I believe.

Comment: See [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=Qs-xdYBQ_5wC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=abel%27s+lemma+test&source=bl&ots=dbDtGcWjAF&sig=dihWzp4XfhNJVVyl7aZ4ukpvtZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SlHhUYunLbe84AO-4oDADw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=abel%27s%20lemma%20test&f=false) for a proof using Abel's lemma.

Comment: @ Arthur: This was my original attempt, but I erroneously assumed that $\sum a_k$ converges absolutely; $|\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}a_{i}x^{i}| \le \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}|a_{i}x^{i}| \le \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}|a_i| \lt \epsilon$. So let me try Abel's lemma .... TY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define

$$R_n = \sum_{k = n}^{\infty} a_k$$

and $M_n = \sup \{ \lvert R_k\rvert : k \geqslant n\}$. Then $M_n$ decreases to $0$, and using $a_k = R_k - R_{k+1}$ a summation by parts yields

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = m}^n a_k x^k &= \sum_{k = m}^n (R_k - R_{k+1})x^k \\
&= R_m x^{m-1} + \sum_{k = m}^n R_k(x^k - x^{k-1}) - R_{n+1}x^n \tag{$\ast$}
\end{align}

for $1 \leqslant m \leqslant n$. For $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, we obtain

\begin{align}
\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = m}^n a_k x^k\Biggr\rvert &\leqslant \lvert R_m\rvert + (1-x)\sum_{k = m}^n \lvert R_k\rvert x^{k-1} + \lvert R_{n+1}\rvert \\
&\leqslant \Biggl( 2 + (1-x)\sum_{k = m}^n x^{k-1}\Biggr) M_m \\
&= (2 + x^{m-1} - x^n)M_m \\
&\leqslant 3 M_m
\end{align}

uniformly in $x\in [0,1]$.

If we don't restrict to $x \in [0,1]$ and allow arbitrary complex $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, taking the absolute value of each term in $(\ast)$ yields the estimate

\begin{align}
\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = m}^n a_k z^k\Biggr\rvert
&\leqslant \Biggl( 2  + \lvert 1-z\rvert \sum_{k = m}^n \lvert z\rvert^{k-1}\Biggr) M_m \\
&\leqslant \biggl( 2 + \frac{\lvert 1-z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}\biggr) M_m.
\end{align}

Thus, for every $K \geqslant 1$ (and $1 \leqslant m \leqslant n$) we have

$$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = m}^n a_k z^k\Biggr\rvert \leqslant (2 + K)M_m$$

and hence uniform convergence on the (closed) Stolz region $S_K = \{ z : \lvert 1-z\rvert \leqslant K(1 - \lvert z\rvert)\}$. The interval $[0,1]$ is the special case $S_1$.

Comment: Urgh, I started to write the same :-) You was faster +1.

Comment: I know that feeling. It's not too bad when I just started, but when I'm about half through, it's really annoying for a moment or two.

Comment: But I don't mind it. Next time I will be faster ;-)

Comment: Hello All, I thought that to use the Weierstrass test, $|a_{k}(x)| \le M$ for all $x$.  So either $\sum a_{k}$ converges absolutely or there is another series of positive terms that converges.

Comment: @AndyTam Consider $a_k\cdot r^k$ for an $r < 1$. Then Weierstraß gives uniform convergence on $[0,\, s]$ for all $s < r$.

Comment: @Fischer:  Now are you comparing $|a_{k}r^{k}| \le r^{k}$, where $r < 1$, or $|a_{k}r^{k}| \le a_{k}$?  I can see that the Weierstrass test applies in the first case, even though you may be skipping finitely many terms in the beginning.

Comment: @AndyTam Since $\sum a_k$ converges, $\sum a_k \cdot r^k$ converges absolutely. For $x \leqslant r$, $\lvert a_k\cdot x^k\rvert \leqslant \lvert a_k\cdot r^k\rvert$. So you have uniform convergence on $[0,\, r]$ (I took a needless detour in the previous comment).

Comment: @ Fischer:  Ok, I convinced myself that $\sum a_{k}r^{k}$ converges absolutely.  Now, I need to try two approaches.  I never thought of using Abel's theorem this way.  TY