# If a series converges uniformly on $[a+\varepsilon,b) $ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and pointwise on $[a,b)$, is then the convergence uniform on $[a,b) $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

The question arises from the specific series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{k (ex)^k}{(k+1)^2} $, which converges pointwise on $[-1/e,1/e) $ and uniformly on $[-1/e,1/e-\varepsilon] $ for every $\varepsilon>0$.

I found the intwrval of pointwise convergengence and I proved uniform convergence on $[-1/e+\varepsilon,1/e-\varepsilon] $, is this enough to conclude the interval of uniform convergence is $[-1/e,1/e-\varepsilon] $?

Comment: For power series, convergence at an endpoint - here $-1/e$ - of the interval of convergence implies uniform convergence on the closed interval between $0$ and that endpoint, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336364/uniform-convergence-in-the-endpoints-of-an-interval), so indeed you have uniform convergence on $[-1/e, 1/e - \varepsilon]$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. But you don't have uniform convergence on $[-1/e,1/e)$, for uniform convergence on $[0,1/e)$ would imply convergence at $1/e$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, thanks. Can't this be shown without using Abel's theorem? We haven't covered that yet. Or otherwise, for example, how else to show uniform convergence on $[-1/e,1/e-\varepsilon] $ in this case?

Comment: How about [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442707)?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's great, thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer Excuse me, doesn't that method use the convergence of $\sum_{k\ge1} a_k $? But in my series $a_k=k/(k+1)^2$

Comment: At the endpoint $-1/e$, the terms of your series become $\frac{(-1)^k k}{(k+1)^2}$, and that series converges. If your power series has radius of convergence $r$ and centre $0$, then the series converges uniformly on $(-r,0]$ if and only if the series converges at $-r$ (and then it converges uniformly on $[-r,0]$). The same holds at $r$, the series converges uniformly on $[0,r)$ if and only if it converges at $r$, and then the convergence is uniform on $[0,r]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, thank you. Just one more thing: when the endpoint is negative, it can also be shown with Leibniz's estimate of the error, I was actually writing an answer on it. But what about when the endpoint at issue is positive, and $\sum a_k$ doesn't converge?

Comment: Then we know that the convergence is not uniform on $[0,1)$. If the radius of convergence is $1$, the convergence is uniform on $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, but we need a gap, however small, to the endpoint, or the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure sure, since the series doesn't even converge pointwise at that endpoint.... cheers

Answer (score -1):

In general the above statement is false.
Consider, for example, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, that converges pointwise to $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ and uniformly on every compact interval $[a,b]\subset (-1,1)$.

On the other hand, you have $s_n(x) := \sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, and this sequence does not converge uniformly to $f$ in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, though isn't this different from what I considered? A counterexample would be a series that converges pointwise on $[-1,1)$ and uniformly on every interval $[-1+\varepsilon,1)$ but not uniformly on $[-1,1) $, or even $(-1,1) $, wouldn't it? Your series doesn't converge pointwise on $[-1,1)$

Comment: check out Daniel Fischer's comment above